# How to get help of a function of a module in python script

Tags: python, module, operating-system

How to get help of a function of a module in python script, i have tried following.

```
import os 

# Stored all the function in a variable.
os_module= dir(os)

function_module_dict = {}
# trying to use help in script 

for function_name in os_module:
    print function_name
    function_module_dict[function_name] = help(os.function_name)

print   function_module_dict
```

i am getting follwing error ,

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'function_name'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem appears when you call `help(os.function_name)`. Here, `os.function_name` really means "the `function_name` field of `os`", not "the function named after the *value* of `function_name` in `os`".

You need to use `getattr(os, function_name)` instead. Then, the variable `function_name` will be evaluated.

Comment: @MatthieuMoy A hint: pushing a new user into accepting your own answer after another answer has been accepted is against the etiquette.

Comment: Err, I did not push after another answer was accepted, my answer was the only one when I wrote my comment. I was just replying to the comment which said that my answer was the right one informally when there's a way to mark it formally with stackoverflow.

Comment: @MatthieuMoy My answer had been accepted for a while,  then got unaccepted after you wrote your comment. It's not a big deal and I won't bitch about it, it's OP's choice. I just wanted to inform you that I don't think this was appropriate behavior.

Answer (score 3):

`os.function_name` tries to access the non-existent attribute literally named `'function_name'` from the object `os`.

For dynamic attribute lookup, you can use `getattr`. You can use the following code.

```
import os
import pydoc

help_dict = {}
for function_name in dir(os):
    help_dict[function_name] = pydoc.render_doc(getattr(os, function_name))
```

The `help` function returns `None`, not the docstring. To get the help text as a string, use `pydoc.render_doc`.